# Exception starting filter struts2 Unable to load configuration. Document root element "package", must match DOCTYPE root "struts"

Tags: java, exception, configuration, struts2

When I started a Struts2 application in Eclipse I've gotten the exception, please help me on this.

**The exception is:**

```
Mar 12, 2014 8:46:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - file:/D:/IMP/JunoWorjspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:10:52
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:502)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - file:/D:/IMP/JunoWorjspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:10:52
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:446)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:490)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: Unable to load file:/D:/IMP/JunoWorjspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml - file:/D:/IMP/JunoWorjspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:10:52
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:1022)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:225)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: Document root element "package", must match DOCTYPE root "struts". - file:/D:/IMP/JunoWorjspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2Starter/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:10:52
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:119)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:1017)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "package", must match DOCTYPE root "struts".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1621)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1900)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3095)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:921)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:117)
    ... 27 more
Mar 12, 2014 8:46:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Mar 12, 2014 8:46:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/Struts2Starter] startup failed due to previous errors
```

**`struts.xml` file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC  
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"  
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" >

        <action name="getTutorial" class="com.suneel.actions.TutorialAction">

            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>          
        </action>       


    </package>
```

**My Libraries are:**

> asm-3.3,   asm-commons-3.3,   asm-tree-3.3,   commons-fileupload-1.3, 
>   commons-io-2.0.1,   commons-lang3-3.1,   commons-logging-1.1.3,
>   freemarker-2.3.19,   javassist-3.11.0.GA,   ognl-3.0.6,
>   log4j-1.2.17,   struts2-core-2.3.15.1,   xwork-core-2.3.15.1

**My `web.xml` is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Struts2Starter</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

      <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: The error message states precisely what the issue is. Consider starting with a known-good S2 application, like those provided in the complete download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be `struts` tag according to the `struts-2.0.dtd`

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC  
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"  
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

<package name="default" extends="struts-default" >

    <action name="getTutorial" class="com.suneel.actions.TutorialAction">

        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>          
    </action>       


</package>
</struts>
```

Answer (score 1):

It May Help You!!!

Struts.xml file must have struts tag...

add Struts tag before package.

```
<struts>
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default" >

        <action name="getTutorial" class="com.suneel.actions.TutorialAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>          
        </action>       

    </package>
</struts
```

web.xml-->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Struts2Starter</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>UR_FILE.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

      <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

the default namespace is "/" so when you hit page in address bar // slash is there so to avoid this you have to write filling code

```
<struts>
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default" >

        <action name="getTutorial" class="com.suneel.actions.TutorialAction">
            <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">error.jsp</result>          
        </action>       

    </package>
</struts
```

Comment: *the default namespace is "/" * - Where? How this is different from OP conf?